# psql -U user pgrouting authentication failure

Tags: linux, postgresql, authentication

I have a pgrouting database in my postgresql database. The owner is user but when I try to connect using

```
psql -U user pgrouting
```

error occurs

```
psql: FATAL:  Peer authentication failed for user "user"
```

How to solve this?

Comment: Have you configured your pg_hba.conf file? [Postgres Host Based Authenticion](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.2/static/auth-pg-hba-conf.html)

Comment: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.2/static/auth-pg-hba-conf.html

Comment: I edited pg_hba.conf.sample like his....                            #TYPE  DATABASE    USER    CIDR-ADDRESS     METHOD
local   all         all                     trust      [OPTION]       and copied it to pg_hba.conf using                                                            sudo cp /usr/share/postgresql/9.1/pg_hba.conf.sample  /etc/postgresql/9.1/main/pg_hba.conf                                no change

Comment: Are you sure a user name user exists in the db?

Comment: @Grzegorz: Restarting is not necessary. Reload is sufficient. [More in the manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/auth-pg-hba-conf.html): `The pg_hba.conf file is read on start-up and when the main server process receives a SIGHUP signal.`

Comment: `I have a pgrouting database in my postgresql database`. There is no such thing as a database in another database. So you have a PostgreSQL database named `pgrouting`? Please clarify your ambiguous question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you seem to misunderstand the nature of "peer authentication". I quote [the manual here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/auth-methods.html#AUTH-PEER):

> The peer authentication method works by obtaining the client's
>   operating system user name from the kernel and using it as the allowed
>   database user name.

The name of the system user has to match the name of the db user. You don't provide a user-name with the `-U` parameter for this authentication method. While you are, in fact, logged in as the appropriate system user, just issue:

```
psql pgrouting
```

With more connection options like the port if they differ from default values.

Next, you shouldn't use `user` as actual user name. It's a [reserved word](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-keywords-appendix.html) in every SQL standard and in Postgres as well. It's also very confusing to everybody.

If you want to allow login with password, you must add an entry to your `pg_hba.conf` file allowing the [`password` or `md5` (preferably) authentication method](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/auth-methods.html#AUTH-PASSWORD) - and *reload*.

Comment: it worked with sudo thank you...